# How can i create 3d pushpin extension for autodesk forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I want to create 3d pushpin extension for Autodesk forge v7.*. I tried to use this article`
[3D Markup with icons and Info-Card](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card).
But some functions are not working correctly. How can i use it correctly? 
I got this errors in console

[image: errors in console]

Now all functions are working correctly, in data i got undefined for parent. Pushpins are not appeared yet. 
[image: data with undefined parent]

Comment: which functions? questions like this are too broad and hard to narrow down for answers

Comment: See edit. I got errors when move mouse on model

Comment: Looks like you have downloaded the Viewer libraries which is against the developer's license and not technically supported - see relevant terms [here](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js) and always load the libraries from our CDN

Comment: Can you see edit?

Comment: still too little to go on so set up a live environment on jsbin/codepen (can follow this sample [here](https://jsbin.com/saropij/edit?html,js)) and reproduce the issue so we can look into it

Comment: This is my code [here](https://jsbin.com/zuyijiqina/edit?js,console,output). Initialization and extension functions are working, but pushpins dont appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there were a few issues with your code:

- Since Viewer v7 and onwards overlay scenes are managed so you'd need to add custom geometry with:

```
 this.viewer.overlays.addScene('custom-scene');
 this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(this.line3d, 'custom-scene');
```

- Use arrow functions or bind for your callbacks to window and document events such as `mousemove` or `click` otherwise they'd lose their contexts and throw errors
- Necessary styling was not set for the markups to persist their relative positions ...

See [here](https://jsbin.com/ziraxiw/edit?js) with corrections to all of the above:
[image]